# redirect ffmpeg (stderr) output to WHILE READ & retrieve Process ID

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, pipe, io-redirection

I can redirect ffmpeg's `stderr` to `while read`:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -re -i colors.mp4 -vf freezedetect=n=-20dB:d=2 \
-f null - 2>&1 | while read line; \
do if [[ $line =~ "freeze_start" ]] ;\
then echo [`date`] >> freeze_start.log ;\
echo [`date`] ;\
fi ; done;\
echo $! > pid.log
```

The result:

- everytime ffmpeg outputs `freeze_start` to `stderr`, the current date is displayed in the shell and written to `freeze_start.log`
- **PROBLEM:** Some Process ID is written to `pid.log`. Not the Process ID of the `ffmpeg` process.

**How can I retrieve the `ffmpeg`'s process ID with `&` while still being able to use `while read` on the piped `stderr`?**

Where can I place the `&`in order to make that work?

When I add `&`to `...-f null -& 2>&1 | while...` the result is:

- The correct Process ID of the `ffmpeg` process is written to `pid.log`.
- **PROBLEM:** `freeze_start.log` is not created. I guess the `&` interferes with the IO-redirection.

  ```
  ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -re -i colors.mp4 -vf freezedetect=n=-20dB:d=2 \
  -f null -& 2>&1 | while read line; \
  do if [[ $line =~ "freeze_start" ]] ;\
  then echo [`date`] >> freeze_start.log ;\
  echo [`date`] ;\
  fi ; done;\
  echo $! > pid.log
  ```

You can easily create the input `colors.mp4`:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=red -frames:v 1 color001.jpg && \
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=green -frames:v 1 color002.jpg && \
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=blue -frames:v 1 color003.jpg && \
ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i color%03d.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p colors.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a `&` at the end of the whole pipeline and retrieve the PID of the first command in the pipeline with `jobs -p` (not using `$!` here because it would give you the PID of the last command in the pipeline):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -re -i colors.mp4 -vf freezedetect=n=-20dB:d=2 -f null - 2>&1 |
while IFS='' read -r line
do
    [[ $line =~ "freeze_start" ]] && echo "[$(date)]"
done |
tee -a freeze_start.log &

# showing what is what:
ps -f $(jobs -p) $!

# this one is ffmpeg's PID
jobs -p > pid.log

# wait for completion
wait
```

Comment: Thank you, that works great! Where does `tee -a` get its content that it writes to the file?

Comment: The pipeline is composed of `ffmpeg | while | tee`, so the output of the `while` loop  is the input of the `tee` command.

Comment: Why did you use `tee` instead of `echo` or `cat`?

Comment: The `tee` command is meant to replace `echo xxx; echo xxx > file1.txt; echo xxx >> file2.txt ...`. Also, your echo was calling a `date` command, and you were doing it **inside** the `while` loop, which opens and closes the file every time; it's better to keep the forks to a minimum inside a loop and do the redirection outside the loop.

Comment: Can I feed the value of `jobs -p` into the `... echo "[$(date)]"`?

E.g.:
`[[ $line =~ "freeze_start" ]] && echo "[$(date)] - ${pid}"`
...
`pid=$(jobs -p)`

Comment: Inside the pipeline you should be able to use `$!`; not sure how reliable it is but it seems to work `sleep 123 | ps -f "$!" | cat &`